# How to parse complex nested json data from api in react using material UI?

Tags: reactjs, json, material-ui

I need to parse nested JSON data which is coming from an API and need to display it using Material UI in React. I am able to display normal json data but not been able to display a complex nested json data.

**Json Data:**

```
{
    "id": 116,
    "user": "4",
    "title": "Sample",
    "category": "cat",
    "notes": "{\"type\":\"doc\",\"content\":[{\"type\":\"blockGroup\",\"content\":[{\"type\":\"blockContainer\",\"attrs\":{\"id\":\"18d925d3-7523-45b3-a212-612b422a9aa7\",\"textColor\":\"default\",\"backgroundColor\":\"default\"},\"content\":[{\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"attrs\":{\"textAlignment\":\"left\"}}]},{\"type\":\"blockContainer\",\"attrs\":{\"id\":\"709a7ce3-77e8-44cb-9441-9ef0fea84db4\",\"textColor\":\"default\",\"backgroundColor\":\"default\"},\"content\":[{\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"attrs\":{\"textAlignment\":\"left\"},\"content\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"marks\":[{\"type\":\"textColor\",\"attrs\":{\"color\":\"blue\"}},{\"type\":\"backgroundColor\",\"attrs\":{\"color\":\"gray\"}}],\"text\":\"- AI stands for Artificial Intelligence, which refers to the development of computer systems that can perform tasks that would normally require human intelligence.\\n- AI can be categorized into two types: narrow AI and general AI. Narrow AI is designed to perform a specific task, while general AI is designed to have the same level of intelligence as a human being and can perform any intellectual task that a human can do.\\n- Machine learning is a subset of AI that focuses on the development of algorithms and statistical models that enable computer systems to learn and improve from experience without being explicitly programmed. It is widely used in various AI applications.\\n- Deep learning is a subset of machine learning that is inspired by the structure and function of the human brain. It involves training a deep neural network with multiple layers of interconnected nodes to recognize patterns and make decisions.\\n- AI has numerous applications across various industries. For example, in healthcare, AI can be used for medical diagnosis, drug discovery, and personalized treatment plans. In finance, AI can be used for fraud detection and algorithmic trading. In transportation, AI can be used for autonomous vehicles and route optimization.\\n- Despite the many benefits of AI, there are also concerns and challenges associated with its development and implementation. Some worry about the ethical implications of AI, such as privacy issues, bias in algorithms, and job displacement. Additionally, developing AI systems that are safe, reliable, and trustworthy remains a challenge.\\n- The field of AI continues to evolve and advance rapidly. Researchers are constantly developing new algorithms, techniques, and models to improve the capabilities of AI systems. There is also ongoing debate and discussion regarding the future impact of AI on society and how best to regulate and govern its development and use.\"}]}]},{\"type\":\"blockContainer\",\"attrs\":{\"id\":\"65bcbc29-b852-48aa-b2d4-c650ac5e7eae\",\"textColor\":\"default\",\"backgroundColor\":\"default\"},\"content\":[{\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"attrs\":{\"textAlignment\":\"left\"}}]}]}]}"
}
```

**App.js:**

```
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
  import { Container, Typography, Card, CardContent, Grid, Box } from '@mui/material';
  import axios from 'axios';

  function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('https://api.gyanibooks.com/library/get_dummy_notes')
      .then((res) => {
        setNotes(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      })
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
        Notes
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        {notes.map((note) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} key={note.id}>
            <Card>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
                  {note.title}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                  ID: {note.id}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                  Category: {note.category}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                  User: {note.user}
                </Typography>
                <Box
                  variant="body2"
                >
                  {note.notes}
                </Box>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Can anyone please help? Questions: How to parse nested JSON elements(Here its {note.notes}) in ReactJS material-ui based Box? Please provide solution to this issue.

[I am getting this on my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD9G4.png)

I want that `{note.notes}` should be displayed properly using Material UI.

Comment: Are you just looking for [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code you think you are?

Comment: @David  No, I am looking for a better view of {note.notes} object on my page with Material UI.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have think about the view, but not getting the proper view on page.

Comment: @Aach_copro: In the question it appears that you want to parse a JSON string into an object so you can get information from that object.  But then in that last comment you claim that you don't want to use `JSON.parse()` to parse that string to an object.  Then what exactly *do* you want to do?  "I am looking for a better view" is very vague.  If what you *specifically* want to do is get information from that JSON string then the easiest way is likely to parse the JSON to an object and use that object.  Otherwise, what "better view" are you asking about?

Comment: @Aach_copro `note.notes` is a complex object. You need to pull out the data you want, in the format you want, the same way you pull out the data at the top level of the object.

Comment: @David As you can see in image provided , that for simple json object, I am getting parsed info but not been able to get it from complex json object, so I want that parsed info for complex json object also.

Comment: @Aach_copro: So... You want to parse that JSON string into an object so you can reference properties on that object?

Comment: @David Yeah, so that I can give proper styling to it using material UI.

Comment: @Aach_copro: But you *don't* want to use `JSON.parse()` to parse it?  Why not?

Comment: @David Please don't misunderstand me, I want the same parsing for the complex object also.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're having. `note.notes` has a string in it. You need to parse that string into an object. Then access the properties of that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`note.notes` is a string, which contains JSON data.  To access that data you need to [parse that JSON into an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).  Then you can use it like any other JavaScript object.

For example:

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  {notes.map((note) => {
    const innerNotes = JSON.parse(note.notes);

    return (
      <Grid item xs={12} key={note.id}>
        <Card>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
              {note.title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">
              ID: {note.id}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">
              Category: {note.category}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">
              User: {note.user}
            </Typography>
            <Box variant="body2">
              {innerNotes.type}
            </Box>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    );
  })}
</Grid>
```

Notice the use of `JSON.parse()` to parse the JSON string into an object (called `innerNotes` in this example, you have multiple things intuitively called "notes" here) and then that object is used later to output a property (specifically the `type` property in this example, which is the first property on the object shown).

From there you can continue to expand your markup and output whatever other data you want from that object.  But the overall point here is that what you currently have is simply a *string*, and in order to meaningfully extract data from that (JSON) string you first need to parse it into an object.

Comment: On applying your answer provided, I am getting this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. How I should avoid this error ?

Comment: @Aach_copro: Is the JSON value shown in the question the *only* JSON you're de-serializing?  Because that exact value [demonstrably works](https://jsfiddle.net/aw568hdL/).  In your code, are you doing any other JSON deserialization with any other values as well?  Your first step in diagnosing the error will be to debug and identify the exact operation which produces the error and the exact value(s) used in that operation.

Comment: Can you tell me that If the API response has any empty JSON then what should I do , as I am new to web development, so please help me .

Comment: @Aach_copro: If the string value is empty then don't try to deserialize it.  As an example, you might default to an empty object instead: `JSON.parse(note.notes || "{}")`  Or you might check `if (note.notes === '')` and perform some custom logic.  And of course, if there's no data to be deserialized, then you'd also want to introduce conditional logic before trying to output that data.  There's really no magic to it, if you have a condition in which you want to perform a different operation then you'd use `if` statements for code blocks or ternary conditional operators for expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much , Now I am getting a proper response.